# How can I debug what dependencies are taking a long time at boot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

You mentioned in [Rails 3 app server startup time is long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503175/rails-3-app-server-startup-time-is-long) that you had some code for this?

Comment: My co-worker wrote this: https://github.com/nevir/Bumbler

Comment: Bumbler + "alias bungle=bundle" (required in all environments) = bumbler bungle! I'm sorry once I saw that repo I had a few lol moments.

Comment: [This](http://dev.theconversation.edu.au/post/5001465621/how-we-shaved-2-seconds-off-our-rails-start-up-time) could help